# JQuery querySelector : is there benefit to selecting by class AND id?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I inherited some old jquery code, and I notice that the original developer uses query selector ".class #id" all over the place. For example :

```
 $('.red #mydiv')
```

Is this better, worse or exactly the same as

```
 $('#mydiv')
```

And why? Performance reasons?

My curious mind is dying to know!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fastest way is using ID selector: `$('#mydiv')` or `document.getElementById("mydiv")`.

What you could **consider in your specific case** (if the author of that code actually knew what he was doing) is that perhaps the jQuery code is generic in the means:

- The same jQuery code is processed in all pages
- `#mydiv` can appear in multiple pages but in different places
- in some pages it's inside `.red`
- Target only such cases where `#mydiv` appears inside `.red`

therefore

```
$('.red #mydiv').text("Hello, World!")
```

page1.html

```
<div class="red">
   <div id="mydiv">Hello, World!</div>
</div>
```

page2.html

```
<div class="blue">
   <div id="mydiv"></div>
</div>
```

adds an additional layer of **specificity** to the selector.

Comment: Ahhh, I see. That makes sense. In the case I'm looking at though, I can't see a reason to use the class selector.

Comment: @Connemara1 yes, if you cannot find in HTML any meaningful reason for `#mydiv` to be dependent on some parent class, than feel free to improve the performance by removing the useless `.red`. Also take a look around your JS files to make sure `#mydiv` is not wrapped into `<div class="red">` dynamically (like i.e: using jQuery's `.wrap()`)

Answer (score 1):

Performance-wise using id alone is most efficient. However there are valid use cases for having an ancestor class preceding an id.

For example consider a back end template that sets different classes on body depending on route it is currently used on. The id may exist in all routes but you may want to do something specific to it only if that body class exists.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you wanted to capture let's say hover event for all elements with that class or that specific div then this would make sense. Remember that is an OR condition and not an AND so it depends on what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

It probably depends on what you are trying to do.

In CSS, class attributes are typically intended for many elements that need to inherit certain styles, while ID attributes are intended for one particular element that needs to inherit certain styles.

It really isn't a matter of performance; it's a matter of if you need the attributes that would be given by the `.red` class selector, or if all that was needed was the `myDiv` ID.  Additionally, if there is some other Javascript or JQuery code that selects and identifies elements based on their ID or class attributes, then either one may be required for that code to find those elements.

Keep in mind that an ID is intended to be used by only ONE element, while MANY elements may have a class, and, in fact, elements often have multiple classes.

Answer (score -1):

I suppose there is a multiple answers to this question.

First answer would be, if code uses selectors like this, maybe your buddy has been doing it wrong by targeting one unique element - twice. 
The second answer would be, he has a bad html. And he must do that way. 
The third answer, he has a multiple elements on the page doing the same action.